# Mounting a Windows DFS share on Debian box

Tags: linux, debian, windows-server-2012-r2, smb, microsoft-distributed-file-system

I'm trying to mount a Windows Server 2012 backed DFS, which uses a fully qualified domain name, on my Debian linux machine with limited success.

So, what I first tried was:

```
mount -t cifs //mydfsdomain/namespaceroot/sharedfolder /mnt/sharedfolder -o username=un,password='pw',workgroup=WORKGROUP
```

But, I received an error

> mount error(5): Input/output error

After some googling, I was told I needed to pass the argument sec=ntlm or other sec variants, but these tend to result in the following error message:

> mount error(95): Operation not supported

I've tried lots of Googling and followed what was suggested [here](http://mikemstech.blogspot.ch/2012/10/how-to-mount-dfs-share-in-linux.html) and [here](http://mattslay.com/connecting-ubuntu-to-windows-shares-and-dfs-trees/), but I still see the same error messages.

A little information about the machines. The client is running Debian 5.0.10 and the server is a Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard 9600.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried turning off and on again...

Answer (score 0):

I've been wrestling with mounting a Windows DFS as well. I got mine (Debian 3.16.0) to mount *OK*. Here are a few 'gatchas' that I came across. Maybe some of them will help you:

The [Mike's Technology](http://mikemstech.blogspot.ch/2012/10/how-to-mount-dfs-share-in-linux.html) blog that you referenced mentioned that the `-c` option for `cifs.spnego` in `/etc/request-key.conf` is deprecated. Be sure you skip that option. I don't use the `-t` option in the `dns_resolver` line either. See [this page](https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages-3/cifs.upcall.8.html) for descriptions of the options.

I haven't had to use any of the `sec` arguments so I can't speak to those.

Another workaround I had to use was to mount directly to the `//server name/share name` at the root of the DFS tree rather than resolving the FQDN. You can find the server a Windows computer is connecting to using the techniques in [Clint Boessen's Blog](http://clintboessen.blogspot.com/2011/08/how-to-find-what-server-your-dfs.html). I wasn't able to find a useful reference for finding server names in Linux.

Once I got a portion of the DFS mounted, I found that it still had trouble resolving the links to other servers. I added a [mount option](https://www.kernel.org/doc/readme/Documentation-filesystems-cifs-README) `actimeo=0` and this seemed to resolve some sort of attribute caching problem that resulted in an error `object is remote`. Probably not your problem but one you're likely to run into later.

Good luck!